# ASP.NET MVC. JqGrid не отображаются данные

Tags: c#, jquery, база-данных, asp.net-mvc, grid

Я пытаюсь отобразить данные в JqGrid, делал все как здесь [Metanit](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/17.3.php)
за исключением того, что данные брал из БД. Проблема в том, что сетка пустая, хотя данные в списке имеются. Не знаете в чем может быть проблема ?

**Класс, который хочу отобразить**

```
 public class AcademicPerformance{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Student_Id { get; set; }
        public int Semester { get; set; }
        public string Name_Sub { get; set; }
        public int Mark { get; set; }
}
```

**Разметка**

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<html>
<head>
    <title>jqGrid</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <body>
        <h2>jQGrid</h2>
        <table id="jqg"></table>
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#jqg").jqGrid({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetData", "Account")',
        datatype: "json",
        colNames: ['Id', 'Студент', 'Семестр', 'Дисциплина', 'Оценка'],
        colModel: [
        { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 30, stype: 'text' },
        { name: 'Student_Id', index: 'Student_Id', width: 150, sortable: true },
        { name: 'Semester', index: 'Semester', width: 150, sortable: true },
        { name: 'Name_Sub', index: 'Name_Sub', width: 150, sortable: true},
        { name: 'Mark', index: 'Mark', width: 150, sortable: true }

        ],
        rowNum: 5, // число отображаемых строк
        loadonce:true, // загрузка только один раз
        sortname: 'Id', // сортировка по умолчанию по столбцу Id
        sortorder: "desc", // порядок сортировки
        caption: "Данные"
    });
});
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Методы**

```
public ActionResult Cabinet(){
    AppContext db = new AppContext();
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["id"]);
    var list = db.AcademicPerformances.Where(x => x.Student_Id == id).ToList();

    foreach(var el in list)
    {
        academicPerformances.Add(new AcademicPerformance { Id = el.Id, Student_Id = el.Student_Id, Semester = el.Semester, Name_Sub = el.Name_Sub, Mark = el.Mark});
    }

    return View();
}
public string GetData(){
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(academicPerformances);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Структура ответа не соответствует ожидаемой.

http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html - Loading Data - JSON Data

Посмотрите комментарии по Вашей ссылке про версии библиотеки jqGrid.

Comment: Спасибо, что-то я проморгал этот момент.